# track and field word problem

Tags: quadratics

Word Problem:

A track and field runner saves 1 hour by covering 112 km at a rate which is 2 kmph greater than the usual rate. How many hours does he usually take to travel this distance?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you state the source of the problem, show any work you have done, and indicate where you are stuck so that you receive responses that are appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

If the usual rate is $r$ (kph), then the faster rate is ...

At the usual rate it takes ... (time) to cover the distance. (In terms of $r$.)

At the faster rate it takes ... (time) to cover the distance.

Set up and solve an equation.

Final thought: Wow, that is a long distance to run!